# Why Is this My SQL Returning Zeros

Tags: mysql

This is meant to be a query returning ranked results greater than zero.

I'm still getting rows with score zero anyone see why?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS P.`Package_ID` as `id`, 
P.`name`, P.`description`,
(( ((P.`name` LIKE '%test%' ) *100 * 1 ) +
((P.`name` LIKE '%test%' ) * 1 * 90) + 
((P.`name` LIKE '%test%' ) * 20) + 
((P.`description` LIKE '%test%' ) * 30 * 1 ) +
((P.`description` LIKE '%test%' ) * 10 *1 ) + 
((P.`description` LIKE '%test%' ) * 10) )) AS `score` 
FROM `package` P  
WHERE 
   CONVERT(( ((P.`name` LIKE '%test%' ) *100 * 1 ) +
  ((P.`name` LIKE '%test%' ) * 1 * 90) + 
  ((P.`name` LIKE '%test%' ) * 20) + 
  ((P.`description` LIKE '%test%' ) * 30 * 1 ) + 
  ((P.`description` LIKE '%test%' ) * 10 *1 ) + 
  ((P.`description` LIKE '%test%' ) * 10) ),UNSIGNED) > 0
```

Comment: Also post SHOW CREATE TABLE package

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Never found out why ended up using a Having clause